# App crashing and not hitting Application_UnhandledException or RootFrame_NavigationFailed

Tags: windows-phone-7

We can perfectly reproduce the error, so long as the debugger is NOT attached.

Any suggestions on trouble shooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok...

i'll have to follow up later and build a sample solution to repro this

In a view model, we were exectuting navigation, and then on the next line calling a method that called other methods that included callbacks.

We swithed it so the page we navigated to then called that method.

Before the fix...

The app never crashed when debugging, never throws an error.

With no debugger attached, it failed inconsistentely with the emulator. Interestingly enough, it did NOT ever fail with a Samsung Focus, but did fail 100% of the time on a Samsung Omnia.

By fail I mean it crashes, with no exception available to do anything with...

Comment: @Roger.. You can log all exceptions in Isolated Storage encountered in Global Application Error and Email it the next time the application Starts.

Comment: As I said in the title though, if I could get an excption I could do something with it. We were not getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a problem with a singleton. I have a property named Instance and a private variable instance.

```
lock(sync) { if (Instance == null) {instance = new MySingleton(); } }
```

Notice I'm checking for the property name Instance for null, not the private variable instance. This crashed mysteriously, in fact took Visual Studio Express down. I just started cutting out code until I found the mistake.